# Remapping all topics of a machine to a namespace

Tags: ros, remapping, namespaces

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have to machines, one of them configured as the ROS_MASTER.
Both of them are essentially running the same code, but I want both machines to publish messages to different topics, hence I thougt it would be good to put one of the machines into a different namespace.

I did that via `export ROS_NAMESPACE=xyz`

The code base is quite large, and sadly a lot of people used only global topic names during development, which causes ros to NOT prefix those topics ( /topic1 stays /topic1 while topic2 becomes /xyz/topic2).

Is there any other way (for example with the help of remapping) that would allow me to put all of the topics published by a single physical machine to a different namespace?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235683/remapping-all-topics-of-a-machine-to-a-namespace/) by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know the answer, but you might be interested to know, essentially this feature was requested some time ago (to great acclaim). See [HERE](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/209). I can't tell that it has been implemented.

---

Originally posted by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) with karma: 242 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1